# Run-time error VBA upon changing ":" to ";"

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to dynamically add a formula in an Excel sheet using VBA. Something really odd happens. When dynamically creating a formula by using "&" to link together the various components of a string, its gives a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or  object defined error.

This is working (but produces the wrong formula):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 7).Value = "=BDP(f" & row & ":Security Name)"
```

This is not working (produces the above mentioned error):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 7).Value = "=BDP(f" & row & ";Security Name)"
```

Note that the ONLY difference is the ":" in front of Security Name became a ";".

Any idea why this is producing this error?

Also, "Security Name" should also be between quotation marks, but when I double up the quotation marks, or use & Chr(34) I get the same error again.

What I am looking for is a formula to be added to the cell which looks like this =BDP(F4:"Security Name")

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Tried setting the cell's `.Formula` instead of its `.value` property?

Comment: Changing it to .Formula doesnt help unfortunately. The """ quotes I had tried as well, but results in the same 1004 error

Comment: I was going to ask what `BDP` is - `Bloomberg Data Point`.  Now I know. :)  https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/software-updates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a `;` in the actual formula you need to use a `,` in the String you are using.

Also If you write this `""` inside the string it will result in this in your string `"`

So this in you VBA:

`.Formula = "=BDP(f" & Row & ",""Security Name"")"`

will result in this in you actual cell:

`=BDP(F5;"Security Name")` (For me the Row was 5)

(You also can set the `.Value` property instead, but since you´re setting a formula i´d suggest using the `.Formula`)

**Edit:**

The method I used, mentioned in the comments:

```
Sub test()
    BBCode = "XS0357495513 Corp"
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Formula = "=BDP(""" & BBCode & """,""Security Name"")"
    'Range("A1") is like Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to check how this "" syntax works.... If I know what to replace the cell reference of F5 (in your example) into a quoted variable as well, how do I do this? I would like the formula to look like this:
=BDP("XS0357495513 Corp";"Security Name"), and I have the XS0357495513 Corp stored in a variable called BBCode. I would think that it would look like this: .Formula = "=BDP(""" & BBCode & """,""Security Name"")", but this results in that same error again....

Comment: Instead of assigning the formula directly to the cell, write it into a string variable and add a `Debug.Print`-Statement. Look to the output and compare with what you expected. If not sure, write the formula into the Excel by hand and check it in the VBA-Immediate Window with `? activecell.formula`.

Comment: @BartKoolhaas For me no error occurs, i just created a variable `BBCode` and run the line just as you posted it, no errors for me. Maybe there is some error in the "Cellpath", i pasted the method just like I used it in my answer.